# Is it possible to have one static variable on the server for all connections?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, symfony

I am creating a turn-based chinese checkers game. In the body I added onload function that sends ajax request to the server to receive the player number for the connection. But it seems that the response always returns the same number. I tried using `$GLOBALS`, but didn't make it work.

How I want it to work: when I open a new window with the game the connection gets the next number with simple +1. JS code is in the home html page, using Symfony.

Some snippets of the code:

```
<body onload="getPlayerNum()">

var playerNumber = 0;
function getPlayerNum(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:8000/ajaxPlayer",
        method: "POST",
        data: {"playerNumber": playerNumber},
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
}


/**
 * @Route("/ajaxPlayer")
 */
public function ajaxPlayer(Request $request){
    if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest()){
        if (isset($GLOBALS["number"])){
            $playerNumber = $GLOBALS["number"] + 1;
            $GLOBALS["number"] = $playerNumber;
        } else {
            $playerNumber = 1;
            $GLOBALS["number"] = $playerNumber;
        }
        return new Response($playerNumber);
    }
}
```

Comment: You need a storage - database or file.

Comment: Can you post the code at this route `url: "http://localhost:8000/ajaxPlayer"`?

Comment: @GetSet all the code is in the Route, after " /** " line.

Comment: Okay i see now. Is `$_SESSION` at all possible for your goals? That might be able to serve as a "storage" in terms of what @u_mulder is speaking about.

Comment: @GetSet session should be inited with some value. And I suppose this value should be taken from storage.

Comment: @u_mulder im not verse with Symfony. I suppose what i am suggesting is at game start the session is initialized. Then of course if there is a "reset" or "restart" button in the game, the "counter" is reset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Global variables (like the one you're setting in `$GLOBALS["number"]`) are only "global" within the PHP script that's executed when your browser requests `http://localhost:8000/ajaxPlayer`. They aren't automatically remembered by PHP the next time that script is called.

If you use a [session variable](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php), e.g. `$_SESSION["number"] = $playerNumber;`, then it will be present in *any* script your browser requests during a browsing session (by default, that means until you close your browser).

I'm guessing however that you intend for multiple players to play together from different computers, for which you'll need more than that: you'll need a way of sharing data between different sessions.

The most common way of doing this is to use a database. If you are doing your whole app in Symfony, then you probably want to start by reading the [Doctrine](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html) documentation.